# CSS Float causes Blank space in middle

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an assignment where I have to create a website that looks like:

[example site](http://oss.feri.uni-mb.si/images/Vaje/PrimerCSS.png)

I have created this so far: 
I cant remove the white space in between the two divs. I use float:left and float: right

[image: my site]

this is the CSS code:

```
#Vsebina {
width:auto;
position: relative;
left: 200px;
top: -22px;
}


#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh, #Drugi.Vrh, #Tretji.Dno, #Cetrti.Dno, #Peti.Dno,     #Sesti.Dno {
width: 400px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 5px;
}

#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh, #Drugi.Vrh {
border: 2px;
border-style: dashed;
border-color: red;
max-height: 200px;

}

#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh p, #Drugi.Vrh p{
height: 140px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#Vsebina #Drugi.Vrh, #Cetrti.Dno, #Sesti.Dno {
float: right;
}


#Vsebina #Prvi.Vrh, #Tretji.Dno, #Peti.Dno {
float:left;
}
```

The HTML is normal layout, I haven't done any styling in HTML, only the content is there. The file is also too wide, so it makes it vertically scrollable, which is something I want to also get rid off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float left pulls the content to the left of its parent div and float right pulls the content to the right of its parent div.

Seeing by the css code you just need to apply float left. Remove float right to get the desired result.

-Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for this input, it solved my problem instantly.

Comment: Glad to help. Please approve the answer :)

Comment: Is there also a way to make the document not as wide, since now when I open the html file in a browser, it features a scrollbar on the bottom, so the page moves left and right. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: For the div Vsebina apply this width . width: cal(100% - 220px). This might help. I cant be fully sure on this as I don't know the html structure